# Failing to install Debian from partitioned USB drive

Tags: debian, boot, partition, grub2, live-usb

I am new to Linux and have been reading and trying lots of alternatives before writing here.
I am trying to install Debian10 (through NETINST) from a USB stick on a Laptop that normally runs on Gallium OS. I need to provide non-free firmware in order to use wifi, hence the other partitions.

My process is:

- wipe my USB Stick with **dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda**
- create partitions with **fdisk** and assign a bootable flag to the partition that will have the debian install ISO file (**/dev/sda2**)
- use **isohybrid --partok** on the **debian-10.9.0-amd64-netinst.iso** file
- use **dd if=debian-10.9.0-amd64-netinst.iso of=/dev/sda2** to create the bootable Debian installer
- copy the folder with non-free essential firmwares into the other USB partition

When i do the same (without the non-free firmware) on an unpartitioned USB stick, the GRUB installer starts correctly with a graphical interface.

When i do the above (i.e. when trying to boot/install Debian from a partitioned USB) the system displays a GRUB command-line that i cannot use (despite trying browsing contents of the usbstick, i cannot find either vmlinuz nor initrd.img). I am not an expert of GRUB through command-line so maybe I am doing something wrong there, but I cannot get past this phase.

Ideally I would like to boot into Debian through a graphical intallation.

Could anyone see what may be wrong ?

Thank you!
Jon

EDIT1: I would prefer to boot from a partioned USB so i can still use other partitions for other functions

Comment: There is also an [unofficial netinstall ISO](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/10.9.0+nonfree/amd64/iso-cd/) including non-free-firmware available.

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to find an answer, after 2 days of troubleshooting...

Once the GRUB2 Command-Line starts, i **set root=(dev0,msdos2)** where the boot disk is, then i use ls inside that drive to find the file called **grubx64.efi**. I load that file with **chainloader <path_to_grubx64.efi>** then hit boot and voila: the graphical Debian boot/installer starts !